# Numba: when to use nopython=True?

Tags: python, time, numba, jit

I have the following setup:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import timeit
import numba
```

```py
@numba.jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def f(x):
    summ = 0
    for i in x:
        summ += i
    return summ

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def g21(N, locs):
    rvs = np.random.normal(loc=locs, scale=locs, size=N)
    res = f(rvs)
    return res

@numba.jit(nopython=False)
def g22(N, locs):
    rvs = np.random.normal(loc=locs, scale=locs, size=N)
    res = f(rvs)
    return res
```

**`g22` and `g21` are the exact same function, just that one of them has `nopython=True` and the other `nopython=False`**

Now I give them an input. If `locs` is a scalar, then the numba should be able to compile everything since they support `numpy.random.normal()` with this signature. However if `locs` is an array, numba does not support this signature and should go back to the python interpreter.

I run this first just to compile the functions

```
N = 10_000

g22(N, 3)
g22(N, np.linspace(0,1,N))
g21(N, 3)
# g21(N, np.linspace(0,1,N))  # returns an error
```

Now I run a speed comparison

```py
%timeit g21(N, 3)
%timeit g22(N, 3)
%timeit g22(N, np.linspace(0,1,N))
```

which returns

```
274 µs ± 3.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
270 µs ± 5.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
421 µs ± 54.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

It makes sense that `g22(N, np.linspace(0,1,N)` is slowest since it goes back to the python interpreter.

However what I dont understand is that `g21(N, 3)` is  roughly the same speed as `g22(N, 3)`, even though one has `nopython=True` and the other not.

But `g22(N,3)` has the big advantage that it can take another argument, namely `g22(N, np.linspace(0,1,N))`, so its more versatile, however at the same time there is no speed penalty to having `nopython=False`

#### So my questions are:

1. in this case, what is the use of using `nopython=True`, if a function with `nopython=False` achieves same speed?
2. in which specific case is `nopython=True` better than `nopython=False`?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if easily possible it may make sense to just implement the function using supported features. eg. `res=0; for i in range(N):; res += np.random.normal(loc=locs[i], scale=locs[i]);`. For examples using random numbers it would also make sense to call np.random.seed(0) in the function, to get the same values.

Comment: Actually this may be helpful. I did not consider this since inherently a for loop with RV generation seems less efficient than generating them all at once, however when using numba there maybe not much overhead, so this is worth considering. Thanks, I will try this out!

Comment: I testet it. For 10 000 values it is about twice as fast than the Numpy implementation. Due to higher static overhead, the difference is getting higher if the number of values decreases. Internally Numpy very likely does do the same within compiled code. Don't be afraid of loops in compiled code ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. in this case, what is the use of using nopython=True, if a function with nopython=False achieves same speed?
> 2. in which specific case is nopython=True better than nopython=False?

The [documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jit.html?highlight=nopython#nopython) states:

> Numba has two compilation modes: nopython mode and object mode. The former produces much faster code, but has limitations that can force Numba to fall back to the latter. To prevent Numba from falling back, and instead raise an error, pass `nopython=True`.

Note that in Numba will try to compile the code to a native binary in **both modes**. However, `nopython` produces an error when this is not possible while the other produces a warning and cause a fallback code to be used.

For some applications, performance can be critical and so you really do not want the fallback code to be called. This the case for *high-performance applications* for example. Having an error in this case is better than having a code which runs for days instead of few minutes on an expensive machine (like a supercomputer or a computing server). Using different version of Numba can *silently cause a fallback* on some machine due to feature not being supported. I personally always use the `nopython` mode to prevent such case (as the fallback code is generally too slow to be useful) and I consider the object mode a bit useless. Put is shortly, **`nopython` offers stronger guarantees about performance**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not consider the aspect of wanting to be absolutely sure that code is compiled. In that sense it really does make sense to use `nopython=True`. That does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

##### Edit: this answer is wrong, see comment below and read accepted answer instead

---

Well I have continued using `nopython=False`, and it seems that this causes a bit more compilations. Its not very scientific analysis, but it seems that my function is sometimes recompiled when I change various parameters, whereas with `nopython=True` it never got recompiled once it was compiled. So that seems to be a potential difference

Comment: AFAIK, recompilation is not impacted by the use of the nopython mode. Note however that you can specify the *signature* of the function so to build it eagerly. For more information about this, please read: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jit.html?highlight=eager#eager-compilation . Note also that you can provide multiple signatures.

Comment: You are right, I switched back to `nopython=True` and I get the same amount of recompilations, so that was a false flag. Thanks for the comment